# Best method for string comparison in tcl?

Tags: string, performance, compare, runtime, tcl

I have two strings let suppose $a and $b.
I want to compare whether they are equal or not. Which method should I use and why?

I know of 2 methods:
`$a eq $b`
and
`string equal $a $b`

which of these is faster or if we have any other faster way of string comparison in tcl?

Comment: Those are the best methods. You can also use the `==` expression operator and so on, but that's less efficient. (The advantage of `eq` is that it is shorter for many common cases, and `string equal` takes options that let you do more cunning stuff than simple full equality.)

Answer (score 4):

Use whichever is most obvious to you as a human. The two commands actually result in the exact same byte codes:

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {expr {$a eq $b}}
ByteCode 0x0x556045ea6fd0, refCt 1, epoch 17, interp 0x0x556045e1a390 (epoch 17)
  Source "expr {$a eq $b}"
  Cmds 1, src 15, inst 8, litObjs 2, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-6, src 0-14
  Command 1: "expr {$a eq $b}"
    (0) push1 0         # "a"
    (2) loadStk 
    (3) push1 1         # "b"
    (5) loadStk 
    (6) streq 
    (7) done 

% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {string equal $a $b}
ByteCode 0x0x556045ea76d0, refCt 1, epoch 17, interp 0x0x556045e1a390 (epoch 17)
  Source "string equal $a $b"
  Cmds 1, src 18, inst 8, litObjs 2, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-6, src 0-17
  Command 1: "string equal $a $b"
    (0) push1 0         # "a"
    (2) loadStk 
    (3) push1 1         # "b"
    (5) loadStk 
    (6) streq 
    (7) done
```

Considering the very straight-forward byte codes, it is hard to imagine that there can be any faster method.

Comment: Can we get this byte code every command in tcl?

Comment: Sure. Although sometimes it's not so interesting, when the byte codes simply push the words of the command onto the stack and then execute `invokeStk1` to interpret X number of words on the stack.

Comment: Note that we reserve the right to change how a command is implemented in bytecodes at any time, and much better bytecode tends to be generated for procedure & method bodies than for free scripts (because we can generate hidden variables).

Comment: All I/O-related commands are currently handled via one of the `invoke` family of opcodes; the cost of those tends to be much higher than the costs relating to invoking things, as they do buffer manipulation and OS system calls.

Comment: Where do you guys study tcl in so much depth. I also want to go to lower levels of abstractions in Tcl. Can you please suggest me some resources to study from?

Comment: This book is really good:  https://www.magicsplat.com/ttpl/index.html